# Unable to connect to an Oracle XE database from Oracle Sql Devloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I've installed an Oracle 11g XE on a Linux `ubuntu 14.04`, successfully created a user, and imported a database into it.
my problem is , if when I want create new connection for connect with DATABASE hr for example Bring me a message :

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFVE0.png]

the result of `lsnrctl status` is :

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 29-APR-2016 14:01:13

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DrBrm)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't have your listener configured.

One of the possible solutions:
On your ubuntu, connect to graphical user interface through X11, VNC or directly to the computer's screen, log in as the Oracle's installation owner user (usually "oracle") and run the "netca" command. This will start the Net Configuration Assistant when you can configure the listener, address resolution and other things.

Regards.